# Multipanel plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have bar charts faceted by stock symbol name:

[image: barchart-by-symbol]

I would like to be able to add a little "subplot" of an indicator below each plot, like this:

[image]

Is this possible with ggplot2?  I thought of a secondary axis, but most often there is no linear relation between the main plot axis and the indicator axis (so using `sec_axis` is not an option).

Thanks!

Comment: `facet_grid`, `facet_wrap`, or the package `gridExtra`. More likely (given this use case) the latter.

Comment: @r2evans `facet_grid`, `facet_wrap` -- used already. `gridExtra` -- an option, thanks, but it's just so... wrong, unnatural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these appear to be categorically different types of plots, I think you'll have better luck creating separate plots and then rendering them together. Here's one solution using `cowplot` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

#sample data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)), volume = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,volume)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

plot_grid(p1, p2, align = "v", ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.8, .2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

### Edit

Continuing to build on this kludgy example to support the concept of faceting. Ignore the ugly graph, it's smooshed due to image size constraints.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)

#sample data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)), volume = sample(1:10, 400, replace = TRUE), group = letters[1:4])

plots <- list()

for (j in unique(df$group)){
  plot_df <- df[df$group == j, ]
  
  p1 <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~group) +
    xlab("")
  p2 <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x,volume)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  
  p_out <- plot_grid(p1, p2, align = "v", ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.7, .3))
  
  plots[[j]] <- p_out
  
}

do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Can you facet then by another variable (stock symbol)?

Comment: @DmitryZotikov - the example above doesn't really lend itself to that. However, you could write a custom function to iterate over each group (stock), generate both of your charts, and then `cowplot()` them together.

Comment: how come it doesn't? As for the `cowplot()` -- looks like a bit of a kludge to me, but thanks, I'll have to resort to it in case there isn't a better solution. Besides, I feel like this multipanel functionality should be a part of ggplot2.

Comment: @DmitryZotikov - you'll have to ask the developers of `ggplot2`, but it's pretty hard wired into the design paradigm of `ggplot2` to support one set of scales per plot. Your example here has different scales and different geoms in each plot. `cowplot` provides some pretty nice functionality to merge fundamentally different types of plots together and align them where it's reasonable to do so, i.e. they share a common x-axis as in this use case. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) for other examples.

Comment: You're not alone in that opinion, Dmitry, but unfortunately it appears that the maintainers do not strictly agree (or at least not enough to do something), as this has been a "discussion" on SO and similar sites for many years. (For a related example, it took much discussion to include a second axis, with the original premise against it being effectively protecting the user from making a confusing plot. I don't disagree that multiple axes can be confusing, but there are certainly times when it is feasible. Which is why they eventually provided a mechanism, I believe.)

Comment: @DmitryZotikov - check the edit above to support what I think you're after...ignore `reprex` messing up the plot, it renders just fine when not constrained by the dimensions available.

Comment: @Chase, the `cowplot` + `plot_grid` combo looks alright! Thank you. Let's wait for more suggestions a bit, and I'll mark your answer as accepted if there's none.

Comment: @r2evans, oh yes, it's true, I agree.

Comment: @DmitryZotikov - happy to help. That's the same basic workflow I use for many plots at work...not financial data, but same concepts. You'll likely want to decrease the margins around the plots so they can sit closer to one another. [This page](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/31) is a good reference for dealing with those issues.